# SQL Case Statement Proper Aliasing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 query where I am using a case statement in the Select statement.  I want to know what the "correct" way of doing it is.

Each format seems to work perfectly fine, but I was wondering if there is some redundancy between the different selects or something.

Sample formats:

```
SELECT 'isItemDisplayed' = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END FROM myTable

SELECT isItemDisplayed = CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END FROM myTable

SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS isItemDisplayed FROM myTable

SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS 'isItemDisplayed' FROM myTable

SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END isItemDisplayed FROM myTable
```

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS isItemDisplayed FROM myTable` would be most standard conform I think.

Comment: Just don't use single quoted aliases like this one: `'isItemDisplayed'` See: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases)

Comment: Even if this is *mostly* a preferences thing, there are good practices. Here is a relevant post: https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases

Comment: Any particular reason not to use the quotations @ypercube?

Comment: If you need to use punctuation around a column name, you should be using square brackets ([]) instead.

Comment: @ImGreg because it's deprecated. See the linked blog post.

Comment: Sorry, actually only the `'column_alias' = expression` is deprecated and not the `expression [AS] 'column_alias'` but I still find it very confusing to see string literals used as aliases. Column names and table names should not be confused with data.

Comment: @juergend the standard actually says to use double quotes for the name, with no `AS`.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Standard says either double quotes or no quotes at all. And the `AS` is optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with the CASE statement. You can create a column alias for any expression in the select list, including simple column names (ie: to re-name to match client code), literal expressions, function calls, etc. But continuing with your CASE example, there are some things to know.

I almost never see it this way, but the ANSI Sql standard says to use double quotes for the name, like so:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END "isItemDisplayed" FROM myTable
```

What I do commonly see are the 3rd or 5th options from your original question, shown below. Either is fine:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END As isItemDisplayed FROM myTable

SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END isItemDisplayed FROM myTable
```

Either of these also allow you to encase the names in square-brackets (`[]`) if you want a name that conflicts with a reserved word or uses spaces. I would avoid any that use the `=` syntax, as it could confuse someone that you're looking for a boolean result. The other bit advice I can give here is to pick one style and stick with it in a current environment. *Consistency!*

Answer (score 3):

Referencing the example at the bottom of [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) page, I would say:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS isItemDisplayed FROM myTable
```

because it explicitly defines `isItemDisplayed` as the name.

I personally would prefer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS [isItemDisplayed] FROM myTable
```

because it covers for reserved words(even though you should never name anything the same as a reserved word) and you can include spaces.

According to [this](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) blog, not using any explicit identifier(`=` Or `As`) is poor practice.

There is no advantage to using single quotation marks around an alias, besides the SSMS showing the name as a different color, maybe making it stick out?

Comment: You missed the point of that blog post. It shows preference for `=` vs. `AS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one which is preferred:-

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS isItemDisplayed FROM myTable
```

The first two are used to compare the results of the CASE statements against the name. And the last to results which we are assigning as the ALIAS.

Just found this [link](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) interesting(As mentioned by Lamak in comments):

> Personally **I find the single quotes around aliases to be distracting,
> making the select list tougher to read no matter which aliasing
> convention you use.** All alias names are strings; why would I want to
> make it look like it is intended to be data? Also note that #5 and #6
> are not defined in any standard, they just seem to be allowed into the
> syntax

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is about ANSI SQL standard, and peculiarities in Microsoft implementation

first, 1st = 2nd statement, and 3rd=4th=5th, but 1st != 3rd, as it compares, while the 3-5 returns value - UPDATE: for MS SQL all these queries are the same, for some other DB they are can be different

anyway, we can simplify your question to just to these two questions:

**what is the proper way to escape identifiers**

if you use identifier which cannot be mixed with reserved words - you do not need to enclose it with any special symbol, but if you're not sure - it is better to use them

standard SQL define `"` symbol as identifier delimiter, but MS SQL supports additional ones (like []), so you can use any of them, but `"` is preferable, check out http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference/Data_structure_definition/Delimited_identifiers

**should we use `AS` or not**

keyword `AS` is optional in SQL standard, and its optional in MS implementation, but this cannot be true for all DBMS

check http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt - keyword [ AS ] - which means optional for this document

**finally answer:**

to be sure that your query always works as expected - use escaping and use AS keyword, this will help you in case of another DB or if some incompatible changes will be introduced in new versions of MS SQL

so, this query will be better:

`SELECT CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS "isItemDisplayed" FROM "myTable"`

Comment: I suppose you haven't used SQL-Server or you have not come across this syntax. There is no comparison in the 1st and 2nd statement. All 5 are equivalent in SQL-Server (except for the 1st which is deprecated in recent versions.)

Comment: @ypercube I actually didn't tried all queries in ms sql, as I dont have it installed right now, but from general SQL point of view - it is comparison, if MS SQL has added special syntax for AS - you're right, I havent used it and do not suggest to use it, as it is confusing